# Got image data in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have imported a vhd file from local network to the EC2 and have the data in the S3 bucket. It ran properly. I accidentally terminated the EC2 image that was created. I still have the data in the S3 bucket in parts. Can I use that data, or do I have to re-upload the image? It's 40gb and would take over one work day to push to the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re started the conversion task and re-uploaded the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you do not specifically remove your file from your S3 bucket you should be able to use it again from any future EC2 instance.  For example, you could use the aws-cli to "copy" the file from the S3 bucket to any number of EC2 instances.

If you had used the `aws mv` or `aws rm` command, then I would expect the file to be gone.

The bottom line is, if the file is still in the bucket, then you can still use it provided you have the permissions set correctly.

Comment: Would you have any further details on how to do this? I'm not seeing any documentation for this particular use case.

Comment: I'm not a big windows guy but there is some information here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import